# How To Track A Mask In OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

so far ive written a program that uses my webcam and isolates all the colours except green. So, there is only going to be one green circle as there is nothing else green in my room (ill attach an image below), but i was wondering how i could track the mask and get the position of the x and y and either store it in a variable, or print it to the terminal, thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pil64.png

````
from cv2 import VideoCapture
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import os

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
    
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    low_green = np.array([50, 50, 100])
    high_green = np.array([100, 150, 255])

    mask =cv.inRange(hsv, low_green, high_green)
    res = cv.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = mask)

    cv.imshow("frame", frame)
    cv.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv.imshow("res", res)

    k = cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()

cv.waitKey(0)```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure if it Is possible, but maybe getting the centre of the mask and then tracking that point?

Comment: check this : https://medium.com/xailient/face-tracking-in-python-using-xailient-face-detector-and-dlib-8345c5db27b8

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/ has a bunch of tutorials. some of them deal with "contours" and "moments", and some of them deal with "connected components (with stats)". given a mask and either of those options, you can calculate a bounding box or a center of mass.

Comment: Find contour of the `mask` and calculate its moments. You can extract its centroid and display it on your screen: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html